# Will we need CSS Reset if we don't consider any version of IE (Internet explorer)?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Will we need to use a CSS Reset if we don't consider any version of IE (Internet Explorer)?

I'm making a website where I don't necessarily to consider any version of IE. Would it be OK to not to reset anything for Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera?

Is it only IE which forces us to use a CSS reset, or do other browsers also have inconsistencies?

Comment: Since when were CSS resets an antidote for the IE poison?

Comment: @BoltClock - In defense of the OP, the majority of the other browsers have much similar rendering. When using a CSS Reset, the change is most noticeable in older versions of IE.

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/ - perfectly sums up my feeling on the use of resets (I don't use them, and that article explains why).

Comment: @thirtydot @BoltClock - absolutely agree with you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would still need to if you want to support many browsers. It is not only Internet Explorer that needs reset.

Which browser was it, I forgot, but either it was Firefox or Opera that had different default settings too, not just IE.

Nevertheless, it is a safe move to do, and you can rest assured that it will save you a few problems.

Usually, a reset is only about a few kilobytes, which is not much.

Comment: I know reset is good but some newbies asked me for more clearance on the necessity of Reset. It's a common myth that only IE having consistencies, but yes as you wrote, other browser are also having consistencies.

Comment: Every browser has a different default setting, it's not determined by the spec but the browser vendor.

Comment: I put up a test on my website.
http://joshtime.com/defaulttest.html  

I tested on Chrome 9 and Firefox 3.6 (latest). The H1's both had the same font size of 36px. Then, I went to Opera 10.5, and the H1's font size was 40px. The differences are small though. In my opinion, it just depends if you want to be pixel perfect or not.

Answer (score 3):

The point of css reset files isn't solely to make certain functionality work in older versions of internet explorer, it's to make the job of presenting using css the same between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post here should give you a good idea WHY to use RESETS and how it isn't ONLY about IE (flavours) that cause problems:

> ... there are all kinds of
>   inconsistencies, some more subtle than
>   others. Headings have slightly
>   different top and bottom margins,
>   indentation distances are different,
>   and so on. Even something as basic as
>   the default line height varies from
>   one browser to another—which can have
>   profound effects on element heights,
>   vertical alignments, and overall feel.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/

Answer (score -3):

You always should use a reset.

Comment: not really a valid answer with any proof.  His question is more to is IE the only one to blame for reset requirements.

Comment: What @Jakub said. Whether or not to use a reset is a choice, nothing more, and there are perfectly valid arguments [not to use them](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/) as well.